# Make query more efficient

Tags: sql, performance

How can I make the following more efficient? It's currently taking me 22 seconds to run:

```
SELECT Id, PNumber, ClassId, ClassType, CreateDate, EndDate 
FROM dbo.tbl
WHERE DATEDIFF(d, EndDate, GETDATE())< 0 OR EndDate IS NULL 
AND ClassType NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
AND ClassId IN
( SELECT MAX(ClassId) FROM dbo.tbl 
WHERE ClassId IN (SELECT ClassId FROM dbo.tbl2 WHERE PNumber= '132456789')
GROUP BY PNumber)
```

Comment: Do you have the proper indexes?

Comment: Yes, we've checked those already.

Comment: 1) tell us what DBMS as performance tuning varies by SQL product.  and 2) post the explain/query plan.  We really cannot tell much without that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.PNumber, A.ClassId, A.ClassType, A.CreateDate, A.EndDate 
FROM dbo.tbl A,
(
    SELECT MAX(tbl1.ClassId) AS MaxClassId FROM dbo.tbl tbl1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.tbl2 tbl2 WHERE tbl2.ClassId = tbl1.ClassId AND tbl2.PNumber= '132456789')
    GROUP BY PNumber
) B
WHERE ( A.EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(d, A.EndDate, GETDATE())< 0 )
AND A.ClassType NOT IN ('A', 'B', 'C') 
AND A.ClassId = B.MaxClassId
```

Run it and let me know your result.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be able to possibly supply a better query but need clarification.  Your query portion of

```
 AND ClassId IN ( SELECT MAX(ClassId) 
                          FROM dbo.tbl 
                          WHERE ClassId IN 
                             ( SELECT ClassId 
                                  FROM dbo.tbl2 
                                  WHERE PNumber= '132456789')
                           GROUP BY 
                              PNumber)
```

Will return only a single "ClassID" record.  Since the ClassID is the same in both tables, you don't need to go through all what you have and it can be simiplified down to.

```
 AND ClassId IN ( SELECT MAX( ClassId )
                     FROM dbo.tbl2 
                     WHERE PNumber= '132456789' )
```

Since your PNumber is a single number, no need to group by it, it will only return the max() class for that ID anyhow.

So the question... Were you intending on getting only a single ClassID and run from that?

Now, that being said, I would rewrite it so THIS is the first query... Get the one CLASS ID you are concerned with, then get all other entries of this type with the other criteria.

```
SELECT 
      T.Id, 
      T.PNumber, 
      T.ClassId, 
      T.ClassType, 
      T.CreateDate, 
      T.EndDate 
   FROM 
      ( SELECT MAX( T2.ClassId ) MaxClass
           FROM dbo.tbl2 T2
           WHERE T2.PNumber= '132456789' ) OneClass
         JOIN dbo.tbl T
            on OneClass.MaxClass = T.ClassID
          AND NOT T.ClassType IN ( 'A', 'B', 'C' )
          AND ( T.EndDate IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(T.d, T.EndDate, GETDATE()) < 0  )
```

Also notice, I applied all alias.field references to keep clear which table the fields are coming from, especially when any joins are concerned.